# How to add both head and tail Delimiter frame decoder in Netty 4?

Tags: netty

I just started coding on Netty 4 and found it seems to only support singular Delimiter even though it claims to support multiple delimiters. The fact is that it supports using multiple delimiters interchangeably instead of concurrently.

The reason why I need both head and tail delimiter is for the sake of speed when there are cases of packet loss or out-of-order packets received.
E.g. my frames look like this: $_{LEN}{DATA}\r\n

So the head delimiter for me is $_ while the tail one is \r\n.

Say there are multiple packets received in one frame while some of intermediate packets get lost during transmission, if without $*, the decoder has to keep searching for \r\n to determines the end. What if \r\n is also lost, thence it has to search for the next \r\n instead of hitting the $* that leads a new message...

But it seems existing Netty DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder could not support what I want above. How should I implement my own for this purpose?

It looks to me Netty FrameDecoder design does not take into account of packet loss or packer out-of-ordering cases? I might be wrong in this with Netty. Please kindly if there's someone who can shed me light on this.

Comment: Are you using udp or tcp streams? On udp streams you generally don't resplit the received bytes

Comment: tcp streams: the server runs in a cloud data center, the client devices are connected via either WiFi LAN or 3G/2G SIM mobile wireless WAN. Hence the network can be unstable and susceptible to network interference that usually cause packet loss...

Comment: Notice that tcp guarantees you either the data as is (so no modifications), or a connection error. This means that no part of the packet should get lost

Comment: TCP cannot promise delivery, but it can guarantee that either the packet will be delivered and acknowledged within a timeout (4 minutes IIRC), or you will get an error response. In case of an error (say a packet loss) will Netty raise an exception and/or ignore that lost packets but keep reading other packets...In whichever cases, packet loss does happen esp. in a wireless environment and use a good frame delimiter decoder is a technical choice we should make in the design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using Netty's LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder for both brevity and efficiency that matters to both client and server side packet frame decoding. My messages are of this format: \r\n$LEN$DATA\r\n$LEN$DATA

```
ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
p.addLast(new LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder(1024,2,4,0,6));
```

Depending on the client environment, Netty library may or may not be used in client connection and communication. But with this message structure, it can be always easily achieved in writing a relatively robust and efficient frame decoding code.

Answer (score 0):

I think the DelimiterFrameDecoder assumes a lossless ordered input stream. If your lower level transport layer in your pipeline is not a lossless ordered connection, then you will need to implement your own frame decoder that handles lost data and out of order frames by implementing checksums and frame IDs or some other protocol strategy.

Comment: In a noisy wireless network environment, packet loss or out-of-order can be quite common. But I think DelimiterFrameDecoder or other delimiter frame decoders provided in Netty does support recovering (I mean the ability to eventually find the correct start packets) from a stream of incoming bytes mixed with corrupted or missing bytes. The major difference among those decoders to me is the efficiency to do: 1) speed in locating the new good start packets; 2) waste fewer bytes in getting the good packet;  But I found one simpler way with LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder.

Comment: Besides, for packet corruption or loss, I implemented app-level logic to do the guaranteed messaging by relying on ACK message from the receiver side. Of course the message must be cached first before receiving ACK and will be deleted after receiving ACK from the receiver.